# How to get taxonomy name in custom taxonomy template?

Tags: php, wordpress

> I would like to show custom taxonomy name from a page to custom
>   taxonomy template.
>
> e.g My all taxonomies are displaying on a page(xyz) and when i click
>   on particular  taxonomy name it goes to my custom taxonomy template
>   (taxonomy-mycustom_tax.php ) but in this page i could not get name of
>   taxonomy from URL.
>
> taxonomy name seeing in URL
>   like(http:/site_name/cust_taxonomy/name_of_term/).

i have also tried like this way..

```
<?php 
$slugs = explode('/', get_query_var('category_name'));
$currentCategory = get_category_by_slug('/'.end($slugs));
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the taxonomy name in the taxonomy-taxonmyname.php file you can use the following code.

```
single_cat_title('prefix', bool $display=true );
```

The function has two arguements.

See more about this on https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/single_cat_title/